# Can't center text with a large font

Tags: html, css

I tried line-height,etc but it seems that when the content has a large font, it produces an extra white space above and below. Is there a way to make the container get the exact height of the content excluding the spaces from above? And also the same with other browser? I am now having a massive hair loss about this. Thanks!

Here's the css:

```
.raf {
    margin: 20px auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.text {

    font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 52px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    letter-spacing: 17px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 94px;
    height: 54px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.innerText {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
}
```

Html:

```
    <div class="text">

        <div class="innerText">

            39

      </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.text {
font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
color: #000000;
font-size: 52px;
font-weight: bold;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
letter-spacing: 17px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
width: 111px;
height: 54px;
overflow: hidden;
line-height: 1;
}
.innerText {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
border: solid 1px #CCC;
padding-left: 17px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes it made .innerText centered, however the content of that div is not centered. http://jsfiddle.net/rhc24uu6/

Comment: It's due to the letter-spacing of 17px. I've updated my answer by adding 17px to the width of .text & setting a padding of 17px to .innerText

Comment: Hi Dave, I tried adding 'text-align:center', but it show no effect. By the way, I want it to be vertically and horizontally aligned. I tried vertical-alignment:middle and display:table-cell, it centered the .innerText, but the content inside still has white spaces from top and bottom, please help... really desperate with these.